# Antlr3 C# on .Net Core migration not finding partial class

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, antlr3, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to migrate a project from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net Core 3, said projects contains also a MathParser based on Antlr3.
I used the nuget package Antlr3.Runtime (3.5.1) and it seems to correctly create the files needed under MyProject\obj\x64\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 but then those files seems to be unreachable by the application.
To be more specific the created file MathParser.cs contains a piece of the partial class MathParser, the other part of which is in MathParser.g3.cs, but that is not considered.
In the starting project the files are created in the same way (and are identical) and the only exception is that they are in the subdir MyProject\obj\x64\Debug, without the additional folder "netcoreapp3.1".

I really don't get how the .Net Framework 4.8 can seemlessly load MathParser.cs after compiling (and creating it) but .Net Core can.
Any help? Thanks